# How can I disable the Screen Saver on the login window?

Tags: macos, mac, screensaver

How can I disable the Screen Saver on the login window?

Comment: -1, the accepted solution is unclear. It should indicate what to place in the plist file.

Comment: The accepted solution should be the one proposed by Kurt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the .plist file at `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver` either using a text editor, Plist Editor (requires the OS X Developer Tools) or the `defaults` command in Terminal to remove the screensaver at login window.

Like this:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver loginWindowIdleTime 0
```

Comment: how to edit it there? what to add, or what to set, or what to delete?

Comment: What does your `com.apple.screensaver` file have in it? Can you post the contents to [Pastie](http://pastie.org/)? For what its worth, using `defaults` to read my file returns [this](http://pastie.org/1483439) and I don't ever get a screensaver. Note however that I'm running 10.6.6, so if your file uses the old (XML) style of .plist, don't sweat it. You could just try trashing the file too.

Comment: -1, doesn't work for me under Mountain Lion.

Comment: The file is a binary plist file (under 10.8 anyway) and to be edited with a text editor must first be converted using `plutil -convert xml1 /Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist`. Then the file can be edited and the screen saver changed.

Answer (score 16):

I believe this does the trick (at least it seems to have worked for mefor several hours now):

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver loginWindowIdleTime 0
```

This disables the screensaver in the loginwindow.

Comment: I believe this should be the answer since I always use it on my servers.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible to disable the login screensaver in Mountain Lion due to a bug. According to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4540671?start=0&tstart=0 the best you can do is log into root's screensaver settings and change it to Message which uses less resources.

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16515/21181 for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I don't understand yet, the solution in the accepted answer didn't work for me. Below is an alternative method that actually *did* work for me.

Before doing anything, i noticed that a file called `com.apple.screensaver.plist` did not yet exist in `/Library/Preferences/`. But issuing the `defaults` -command as mentioned in the accepted answer created this file with correct `loginWindowIdleTime`-entry just fine. This was confirmed both with `defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver` as well as by manually confirming the files' existence and inspecting its' contents.

However, it didn't seem to have any effect on the screensaver-behaviour in the Login Screen whatsoever.

I then used a different approach that actually did work:

1. I opened a command-prompt (Terminal window)
2. First I issued `$ > sudo -s` to become root
3. Then, as root, I started *System Preferences*: `# > /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Preferences`
4. And finally I went into the *Desktop and Screen Savers* Preference-Pane to use the regular GUI to disable the screensaver timeout.

This did the trick for me.

I'm wondering though, if the `defaults`-command perhaps did actually work fine already, just the changed plist-value wasn't picked-up (synced) yet by the (still running?) `screensaver` process…

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that the login screen is not the result of the screen saver, I lock my Mac when I go out. The screen saver appears by itself, even if it is disabled from SysPref.

Comment: Clarification comments should not be added to the proposed list of answers. The original question should be modified to address additional conditions so as to produce the most succinct answers.