# How can I set the Mac OS X screensaver when not logged in?

Tags: macos, screensaver

When logged in to my user account, the screensaver selected in System Preferences is used. However, when on the login screen before logging in or using fast user switching a different screensaver is used. How do I set the screensaver used on the login screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The screensaver for the login screen is the one set for the root (i.e. system) user account. To launch System Preferences as root, use sudo; a Terminal window run:

```
sudo /Applications/System\ Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/System\ Preferences
```

Then you can change the screensaver settings as you normally would. Note that in order to use sudo, you needs to be an admin user.

Comment: The receipe look right, but doesn't work on Lion. The `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist` isn't modified.
On the other hand, directly editing this file works fine, but I won't advise anyone to play with `plist + vi` on this file :[.