# How do I unlock my Mac without having to click my name?

Tags: macos, unlock

In Snow Leopard, at least, I could press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select my name and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the password prompt, but I can't get that to work in Mountain Lion when I've left the computer locked for an extended amount of time.

How do I unlock my Mac without having to click my name when I've locked it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just by typing the first letters of the user's name should select that user. Afterwards, as you say, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will prompt for the password.

Comment: Yup, I've been doing that for years!

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use the Arrow Keys <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> to select the user name you want and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get the password prompt.

Comment: Thanks, that works well too! Sometimes it's not a good thing to be an advanced user - the simple things aren't as obvious when you're used to something more complicated...=)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> still works too, but my problem seems to be that the keyboard is unresponsive after locking if the screensaver kicks in. For now, I'll up the time for the screensaver to kick in as per [How can I set the Mac OS X screensaver when not logged in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/how-can-i-set-the-mac-os-x-screensaver-when-not-logged-in) and hope that Apple fixes this in a future update.