# Why does Mountain Lion keep using the wrong screen saver?

Tags: macos, screensaver

I have my screen saver set to Arabesque. If I move my mouse down to the Screen Saver hot corner, I get Arabesque. If I sit and wait for the screen saver to start automatically, I get Arabesque.

But if I leave my computer for any length of time and come back to it, it's almost always on Message, putting the name of my Mac up for everyone to see. I dislike this behavior. If I go to System Preferences after this happens, it's still on Arabesque, it's just ignoring the setting.

What's going on? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Do you lock your computer before leaving it? If so, you might be getting other settings than your own user's. You might want to try the suggestions here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/how-can-i-disable-the-screen-saver-on-the-login-window?rq=1

Comment: D'oh, yes, I should have thought of this. That question led me to [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16515/4920) on a different question which was exactly what I needed. Add an answer to that effect and I'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer is locked, the screensaver settings for the root user account is used instead of your own. You can change those settings according to the answer to this question: [How can I set the Mac OS X screensaver when not logged in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/how-can-i-set-the-mac-os-x-screensaver-when-not-logged-in/16515#16515)

Answer (score 0):

"Almost" always? Uncheck the use random screensaver button in the Desktop & Screen Saver preferences.

[image]

Comment: If you had read my question you would have seen that Arabesque was indeed selected, not Random.

Comment: I read your question.  No need to be rude. Selecting Arabesque has nothing to do with the state of the "Use random screen saver" checkbox.  I was just trying to be helpful.  Maybe you should edit your question to more accurately describe your problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Mountain Lion doesn't have that checkbox there. "Random" is an option along with all the other screensavers. Even so, the behavior I described doesn't fit your assumption, and I thought you were a bit sarcastic in your answer. I do apologize if that wasn't your intent, and I un-downvoted you.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll un-downvote your question as soon as i'm able.  Right now, my vote's locked in unless the question is edited.

Comment: done.  cheers, mate.